# Remove mouse/cursor design on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse, mouseover

I used this library called Magicmouse.js https://github.com/dshongphuc/magic-mouse-js
I added the CDN and the code and it worked perfectly. However, when using responsive and mobile view on chrome and browsing on mobile, the point stays on where you tap it.

How can I disable this mouse/cursor design when in responsive and mobile view? Is there some code to add in the script file? This one is what exactly on github

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    options = {
"cursorOuter": "circle-basic",
"hoverEffect": "circle-move",
"hoverItemMove": false,
"defaultCursor": false,
"outerWidth": 30,
"outerHeight": 30
        };
    magicMouse(options);
</script>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm maintainer of Magicmouse.js, sorry for come here too late, I've just found your question few hours ago. And thanks to your question, I found a problem with Magicmouse.js now, so I disabled the libs when window's size is smaller than 768px (mobile & tablet). We can use other way to detect if device is truly mobile or not, but it may need some other library to do that and so it will make our libs too large.

If you're still need it, please update new code.

Thank you ! If you have other issue with Magicmouse.js, please create new issue in the repo so I can check it easily.